# PHPMyAdmin crashing?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, lamp

I'm setting up a development server for the first time and currently have the below installed:

- `lamp-server^`
- Symfony2 framework
- PHPStorm

These are all working ok, however I have tried to install PHPMyAdmin from Ubuntu Software Center and about half way through the process bar it freezes (and the app window grays out). Do you know what would be causing the problem? Could it be due to MySQL already having been installed in the `lamp-server^` or something?

Comment: hmm may be its due to already installed MySQL.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was wondering. But would this mean that I have to do a fresh install of Ubuntu and then do each step of apache/MySql (and PHPMyAdmin)/PHP manually instead of just the nice and simple `lamp-server^`? That would be a shame - also, if I go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin I just get a 'not found on this server'

Comment: When installing phpmyadmin try to disable MySQL.

Comment: Thanks @HamzaZafeer, I got lucky with the phpmyadmin link in the answer below - I don't know the process well enough but I -think- I have reconfigured it to work with 'official' default values instead of the parameters that are given to it with `sudo app-get install lamp-server^`....still quicker than installing them all manually! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved - I'm not sure if it's just one of the below steps that fixed it but I followed the instructions on this link:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/phpMyAdmin

The important step for me was below - I just needed to edit the file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and include the following line of code (I don't think the location matters) and save it:

`Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`

After this, I restarted the apache server (`sudo service apache2 restart`) and then I was able to just go to `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` and I got the PHPMyAdmin page loading without problem